# Columns to matrix

Tags: r, excel, awk

I am looking at different positions in a long alphabet sequence that are summarized in an excel sheet. Example, Case 1,2 and 6 have same pattern at position 5 while others do not have a same pattern at position 5..and so on. Also i have another list with all case names (N>30)
Example:(case 1-7). I am trying to achieve the output in excel but i do not mind awk or R. I tried pivot table but it doesn't do the job as required

```
List1.
Case1 5
case2 5
case6 5
Case1 10
case3 10
case7 10

list2.
Case1
case2
case3
case4
case5
case6
case7

output
      5  10
case1 yes yes
case2 yes No
case3 No  yes
case4 No  No
case5 No  No
case6 Yes No
case7 No  Yes
```

Comment: Edited the question and the desired output

Answer (score 0):

this should give you a head start

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=1; next} {print $1, a[$1,5]+0, a[$1,10]+0}' file1 file2 

Case1 1 1
case2 1 0
case3 0 1
case4 0 0
case5 0 0
case6 1 0
case7 0 1
```

converting `0/1` to `Yes/No`, adding header and making it generic for any values are left as an exercise...